# Glob() to pull out images - randomly?

Tags: php

I use this code to get images out

```
$images = glob($reuter. '/'.$url_places.'/*.{jpg,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Works great, but.. its grabbing images in ASC order every time (ie 1,2,3.jpg).

Anyway, to make (image) sliders more intriguing, I need to get those images out - randomly (all images, not just one) like, 3,1,2 jpg or similar.

Any clues how to achieve that using `glob()`? Thx...

Comment: Have you tried [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)?

Comment: @Maiorano84 - Thx for help Maiorano84!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the result:

```
shuffle($images);
```

Comment: Thx for help, does it great now :)